# How to get rid of use strict in gulp file with JavaScript

Tags: gulp

I need to remove all 'strict mode'.  the below code runs without error but my 'strict mode'; does not change to ;

```
gulp.task('bundle', function () {
 var bundled = bundle(bundler())
 if (!production) return bundled;
   return bundled
 .pipe(buffer())
 .pipe(replace(/"use strict"'/g, ';')) // problem line

.pipe(plugins.uglify())
.pipe(plugins.rename({
  suffix: '.min'
}))

.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app'));
});
```

Comment: This idea was useful to me using Drupal 7's aggregate js files option since 3rd party JS was breaking under 'use strict', so thanks for posting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your regexp has a loose single quote in it.

```
.pipe(replace(/"use strict"'/g, ';'))
                  here ----^
```

This regexp will match `'use strict'` and `"use strict"`

```
/('|")use strict\1/g
```

Comment: For others: `npm install gulp-replace` and then include it: `var replace = require('gulp-replace');`